# Can you update a label with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that I am trying to get to update a label.
If I replace the label with a textbox it works fine, but with the label nothing happens!

**An example of a label:**

```
<label id="163" name="163">Some text.</label>
```

**javascript code:**

```
$("#163").val("meep");
```

Comment: This seems to be a jquery question, not an ASP.NET question.

Comment: I believe the HTML standard does not allow IDs to start with a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method sets the value of an input element.  It will have no effect on other elements, including `<label>`

You need to call the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method, which sets the text of any element.

For example:

```
$("#163").text("meep");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<label>` element is not an input control, and it has no concept of a "value". It sounds like you are simply trying to change the text on the label. This can be achieved using the `text(str)` method:

```
$("#163").text("meep");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try text method :

```
$("#163").text("meep");
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, `ID` and `NAME` attributes should not start with a number, though most times this will not actually cause a problem.